# Compare two sheets of data and highlight difference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to find a way to compare two sheets of data in a workbook. The columns are exactly the same. However, the rows are not the same. The conditional formatting would have to compare the cell to all of the cells in a column on another sheet to see if there was a match if yes then color red. If no, then color green.

I have tried another solution provided here but it didn't work since the rows were different.

Is this possible?

This is what I have tried.

Formula:

```
=AND($C1<>"",COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,'Existing Data'!$C:$C,$C1)=0)
```

Highlight is green.

I'm trying to find the ones that are not already in the existing data.

I tried the formula I entered in above.

Comment: remove the `$C:$C,$C1,` in the COUNTIFS()  otherwise it is finding itself and returning 1.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have it working now. Thanks.

Comment: A more efficient way should be `=AND($C1<>"",ISNUMBER(MATCH($C1,'Existing Data'!$C:$C,0)))`. @Scott Craner: Could you confirm that or am I tripping?

Comment: I did: =ISNA(MATCH(C1,'Existing Data'!$C:$C,0))

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes that would be more efficient, countifs will search the whole range while Match will short circuit when the match is found.